# how to make spinner depends on another spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm building a simple app for android which consists of spinners and edittext.
question is I have 2 spinners with arrays in an adapter
**Spinner 1**

```
 ArrayAdapter adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.kendaraan_arrays,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spKendaraan.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

what I want is arrays from spinner 2 is depends on what i select in spinner 1
**Spinner 2**

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected (AdapterView < ? > adapterView, View view,int position, long id){
    if (spKendaraan.getSelectedItem().equals("Mobil")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mobil dipilih", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ArrayAdapter adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.pelanggaran_mobil, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spPelanggaran.setAdapter(adapter2);
    } else {
        ArrayAdapter adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.pelanggaran_motor, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spPelanggaran.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }
}
```

my code above doesn't work, am I making logic/method mistakes?

tl;dr

```
if spinnerA == x{
spinnerB = m
}
else {
spinnerB = n
}
```

since i'm new in android, any example would be very appreciated.

Comment: what is the issue you are getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why your code is not working but following is a example code for you which works as you needed,I hope this will help.

XML layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.stackspinner.MainActivity" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

Spinner spinner1, spinner2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.array1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    if (spinner1.getSelectedItem().equals("mobile")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mobil dipilih",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ArrayAdapter adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.mobile_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    } else {
        ArrayAdapter adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.motor_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

Strings:

```
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Application Name</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

<string-array name="array1">
    <item>mobile</item>
    <item>motor</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="mobile_array">
    <item>Android</item>
    <item>blackberry</item>
    <item>apple</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="motor_array">
    <item>Audi</item>
    <item>BMW</item>
    <item>unicorn</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: thanks it works like a charm !
in my code theres no code like this "spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);"
sorry i cant up vote your answer

Comment: Got it, you can't up vote it but I am happy that it helped you..:)

Answer (score 1):

I just can see that below this line instead of `this` you could write `getApplicationContext()` or `getBaseContext()` So the actual code should be inside `onItemSelected`

```
ArrayAdapter adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getBaseContext(), R.array.pelanggaran_mobil, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

I think it should work right now. Please let me know if you get any problem with this :)