# Connect values with Two spinners

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want that

When I select an item from spinner1, the values in spinner2 change accordingly

for Example

When I select "USA" from spinner1, "Los Angeles" and "New York" are shown in spinner2.
When I select "Germany" from spinner1, "Berlin" and "Munich" are shown in spinner2.

Comment: Find relevant links below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474829/how-to-make-spinner-depends-on-another-spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private void setSpinner1() {
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.cities, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
    String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            loadContentOnSpinner2(countries[pos]);
        }

       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

       }

    });
}

private void loadContentOnSpinner2(String country) {
    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = null;
    if(country.equals("USA"))
       ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.usa_states, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

In arrays.xml (res/values folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="countries">
        <item>USA</item>
        <item>...</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>

<resources>
    <string-array name="usa_states">
        <item>New York</item>
        <item>...</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: i got error in this line

loadContentOnSpinner2(countries.get(pos))

cannot resolve symbol 'countries

Comment: I updated the code. Try again.

Comment: I can't see the Item when runing the program

Answer (score 0):

You have set your second `Spinner` adpater value in First `Spinner` `onItemSelected` this method.

```
CountrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                 // get here State Spinner
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

when you selecte first spinner using OnItemSelectedListener then use below code.

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView,
                        View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

                if(pos == 1){
                  spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
                }else{
                  spinner2.setAdapter(adapter3);
                } 

                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {// do nothing
                }

            });
```