# How to filter spinner based on other spinner selection?

Tags: android, json

I have 3 Spinners citySpinner, regionSpinner,branchSpinner,i am able populate the data in spinners.The Problem is if i selected UP from spinnerRegion  then in  citySpinner i want show only citys related to that region only.Please help me.

In arraylist i am successfully storing data now how to compare that data based on spinner selection?

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> formList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            final HashMap<String, String> m_li;
            m_li = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m_li.put("region", region);
            m_li.put("city", city);
            m_li.put("Branch", branch);
            formList.add(m_li);
            Log.d("DDDD----->", String.valueOf(formList));
```

Comment: fill region spinner after city selected. implement spinner `onItemSelected()`

Comment: Im filling region data and city data but i want filter data based on region selected bro

Comment: use Adpater Interface function like `onItemSelected()` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make spinner depends on another spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474829/how-to-make-spinner-depends-on-another-spinner)

Comment: this question quite different i am loading data from json  not from string@ Nakul

Comment: Can you show the sample json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this in your activity:

```
    final String JsonData = "[ { \"Br.Name\": \"A BRANCH\", \"Region\": \"UP(W)\", \"City\": \"Agra\" }, { \"Br.Name\": \"B BRANCH\", \"Region\": \"UP(W)\", \"City\": \"Bareilly\" }, { \"Br.Name\": \"C\", \"Region\": \"UP(W)\", \"City\": \"Baghpat\" }, { \"Br.Name\": \"D\", \"Region\": \"UP(E)\", \"City\": \"Amhat\" }, { \"Br.Name\": \"SE\", \"Region\": \"UP(E)\", \"City\": \"Bankeyganj\" }, { \"Br.Name\": \"F\", \"Region\": \"UP Central\", \"City\": \"HARDOI\" }, { \"Br.Name\": \"G\", \"Region\": \"UP(W)\", \"City\": \"Ghaziabad\" } ] ";
    spRegion = findViewById(R.id.spRegion);
    spCity = findViewById(R.id.spCity);


    spRegion.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> CityAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main2Activity.this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, getCity(JsonData, spRegion.getSelectedItem().toString()));
            spCity.setAdapter(CityAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

and please replace your citys source in this class code:

```
 public List<String> getCity(String JsonData, String SelectedRegion) {

    List<String> SpCityList = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] citys;
    try {
        JSONArray Array = new JSONArray(JsonData);

        for (int k = 0; k < Array.length(); k++) {

            try {
                JSONObject object = Array.getJSONObject(k);
                String Region = object.getString("Region");
                String City = object.getString("City");

                if (Region.equals(SelectedRegion)) {
                    SpCityList.add(City);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return SpCityList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response but i am not loading data from string array, i am getting data from JSON file

Comment: @PraveenReddy Can you give me a sample of your own json?

Comment: {
"XYZ":[
  {
    "Br.Name": "A BRANCH",
    "Region": "UP(W)",
    "City": "Agra"
  },
  {
    "Br.Name": "B BRANCH",
    "Region": "UP(W)",
    "City": "Bareilly"
  },
  {
    "Br.Name": "C",
     "Region": "UP(W)",
    "City": "Baghpat"
  },
  {
    "Br.Name": "D",
    "Region": "UP(E)",
    "City": "Amhat"
  },
  {
    "Br.Name": "SE",
    "Region": "UP(E)",
    "City": "Bankeyganj"
  },
  {
    "Br.Name": "F",
    "Region": "UP Central",
    "City": "HARDOI"
  },
  {
    "Br.Name": "G",   
    "Region": "UP(W)",
    "City": "Ghaziabad"
  },
]
}

Answer (score 0):

When you parsing then that time to you have to make mapping
For ex HashMap> regionToCity = new HashMap<>();
regionToCity.put("UP", arralist containing Up's city); // this have to be done while you parsing.

Look like

```
regionSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String regionName = regiponList.get(position);
            cityList = regionToCity.get(regionName);
            //setAdapter of city spinner
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Hope you understand what i am saying. try this and then let me know

Its a example for your understanding. what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for ur response bro , I am not able to separate UP city list can plz help me out with some more code

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage data according to your json while you parsing

or

You have to change your json response like

```
{"UP":[
    {
        "Agra": [
                    {"Br.Name": "A BRANCH"},
                    {"Br.Name": "B BRANCH"},
                    {"Br.Name": "C BRANCH"}
                ]
    },
    {
        "Bareilly": 
                [
                    {"Br.Name": "A BRANCH"},
                    {"Br.Name": "B BRANCH"},
                    {"Br.Name": "C BRANCH"}
                ]
    }
],
"MP":[
    {
        "INDORE": [
                    {"Br.Name": "A BRANCH"},
                    {"Br.Name": "B BRANCH"},
                    {"Br.Name": "C BRANCH"}
                ]
    },
    {
        "BHOPAL": 
                [
                    {"Br.Name": "A BRANCH"},
                    {"Br.Name": "B BRANCH"},
                    {"Br.Name": "C BRANCH"}
                ]
    }
]
}
```

and then you can make mapping with region to city list & city to branch list

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show a spinner value based on some other spinner value used below code for example ....

```
 private void setSpinser() {
    spCity = findViewById(R.id.city);
    spRegion = findViewById(R.id.reigon);
    List<String> cityName = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<String> regionName = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> regionAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    cityName.add("Select city");
    cityName.add("Ahmadabad");
    cityName.add("Surat");
    cityName.add("Delhi");
    ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DbInsert.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cityName);
    spCity.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);
    spCity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            switch (spCity.getSelectedItem().toString())
            {
                case "Ahmadabad":
                    regionName.add("Abc");
                    regionName.add("cde");
                    regionName.add("efg");
                    regionAdapter.addAll(regionName);
                    spRegion.setAdapter(regionAdapter);
                    break;
                case "Surat":
                    regionName.add("pqr");
                    regionName.add("stu");
                    regionName.add("xyz");
                    regionAdapter.addAll(regionName);
                    spRegion.setAdapter(regionAdapter);
                    break;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}
```

above method set second spinner value based on first spinner value selected and this method call in mainactivity in oncreate method.