# multiple spinner in which second spinner values should be related to the selected value in first spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner

using 2 spinner first one contains the main category and second one contains the items related to the selected category.
but the second spinner values are not displayed.

```
package com.learning.double_spinner;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner categoryspn,unitspn;
    EditText inputedt;
    Button convertbtn;
    TextView resulttxtv;

    ArrayList<String> categoryarraylist;
    ArrayList<String> weightarraylist;
    ArrayList<String> lengtharraylist;

    ArrayAdapter<String> categoryarrayadapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> unitarrayadapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        categoryspn= findViewById(R.id.categoryspn);
        unitspn=findViewById(R.id.unitspn);
        inputedt=findViewById(R.id.inputedt);
        convertbtn=findViewById(R.id.convertbtn);
        resulttxtv=findViewById(R.id.resulttxtv);

        categoryarraylist= new ArrayList<>();
        categoryarraylist.add("Select Category");
        categoryarraylist.add("Weight");
        categoryarraylist.add("Length");

        categoryarrayadapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,categoryarraylist);
        categoryspn.setAdapter(categoryarrayadapter);

        weightarraylist=new ArrayList<>();
        weightarraylist.add("Kilogram");
        weightarraylist.add("Pound");

        lengtharraylist= new ArrayList<>();
        lengtharraylist.add("kilometer");
        lengtharraylist.add("mile");

        categoryspn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                if (categoryarraylist.equals(1))
                {
                    unitarrayadapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,weightarraylist);
                }
                if (categoryarraylist.equals(2))
                {
                    unitarrayadapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,lengtharraylist);
                }
                unitspn.setAdapter(unitarrayadapter);
            }


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

using 2 spinner first one contains the main category and second one contains the items related to the selected category.
but the second spinner values are not displayed.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29475471/14700539) will help you

Comment: Try change `categoryarraylist.equals(1)` to `i == 1` and `categoryarraylist.equals(2)` to `i == 2`.